# Combine Word files with python-docx and add page breaks

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to combine few Word files in one with python-docx, and separate them inside with page breaks. Each file contains arbitrary elements. I made 3 test files for example, each of them consist 1 paragraph - "Test 1" (2, 3). Here is my code:

```
from docx import Document

docs = []
docsTitles.append('test/Test1.docx')
docsTitles.append('test/Test2.docx')
docsTitles.append('test/Test3.docx')
i = 0
for item in docsTitles:
    docs.append(Document(item))
    if (i != 0):
        docs[0].add_page_break()
        for element in docs[i].element.body:
            docs[0].element.body.append(element)
    i = i + 1
docs[0].save('test/testReport.docx')
```

But testReport.docx turns out like this:

> Test 1
>
> page break
>
> page break
>
> Test 2
>
> Test 3

instead of

> Test 1
>
> page break
>
> Test 2
>
> page break
>
> Test 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi.  Where does "docsTitles" come from?  What lib, that is.  And why is it necessary?

Comment: docTitles is just the list of docx file names as strings. The docs list is those turned into a docx.Document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

Instead of `docs[0].add_page_break()`, it should be `docs[i].add_page_break()`